# Cant do null check in sub query record

Tags: apex, query, childrecords, parent

I have done a parent parent to child query

```
List<Opportunity> opportunityList = [SELECT Id, Field__c, (SELECT Account__c,Contact__c,CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate, Description__c,Id,Note_Type__c,Opportunity__c FROM Child__r) from Opportunity where Id in: opportunityListId];
```

What I want to do is check if child rows have been returned or not

```
for(Opportunity opportunity : opportunityList){
        if(opportunity.Child__r != null){
            //Something happens
}

}
```

However everytime it is entering within the if. Is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: Select query in SOQL never return null, you can check for `!(list.isEmpty())` , then run your logic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The child object sObject list, here `Child__r`, is never `null` if you perform a parent-child query on that relationship. If no child objects are present, the list will have zero size. You can check

```
    if (opportunity.Child__r.size() > 0) {
```

to determine whether to proceed with processing child objects.

Comment: I'm partial to the `isEmpty()` method, as opposed to `size() > 0`, but they'll both accomplish the same thing.

Comment: I'm suspicious of `isEmpty()` because I think its semantic difference from `String.isBlank()` is confusing and prone to NPEs. I wish it was `static Boolean isEmpty(List<ANY>)` and returned `true` for either `null` or `size() == 0`.